# Why is the Periodogram Used as an Estimate of PSD?

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, fourier-transform, power-spectral-density, periodogram

Why is the periodogram method as given by Schuster (1898) - which is not a consistent estimate of the PSD - still used, as opposed to consistent non-parametric methods for estimating the PSD like Welch?

I'm looking at the Signal Analyzer app in MATLAB which seems to switch between the periodogram method with a Kaiser window and the Welch method (also with a Kaiser window).

From Proakis & Manolakis (2006), pg 970: However, in general the variance of the estimate $P_{xx}(f)$ does not decay to zero as $N\rightarrow\infty$." ... "Hence we conclude that the periodogram is not a consistent estimate of the true power density spectrum (i.e., it does not converge to the true power density spectrum)."

Comment: because consistency for the general case is not always as desirable as other features. (I do agree, though, often something else than the periodogram would be better)

Comment: In fact, in application, consistency doesn't matter – you're never observing for an infinite $N$; what matters is always a finite-observation performance.

Comment: But wouldn't that suggest that there would be no point to increasing $N$ when estimating PSD with the periodogram method - aside from reducing leakage, increasing resolution? What then can be said about the variance as N is increased?